# Android: asynchronous call to fragments' onCreateOptionsMenu cause fragment to display wrong ( or none) action menu

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, conditional-statements

I'm implementing an Android APP that has a navigation tab bar (I'm using com.github.devlight.navigationtabbar:navigationtabbar:+ ). It contains 3 tabs (3 fragments), each tab with its own options menu. I'm using viewPager to switch between tabs.

If each fragment has setHasOptionsMenu(true) and its own definition of onCreateOptionsMenu() to inflate its own menu, then I get a race condition.
For example, if I switch to tab 3, then onCreateOptionsMenu() for tab 1, 2, and 3 all get called, and depending on which gets called last, it'll display the option menu for that tab. This is very frustrating, so here's my initial attempt of fix:

Instead of letting each child fragment tab handle menu inflation, I let the parent class handle it. 
In parent class that sets up the viewPager and tabs. I have the following codes:

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = HomePage.this.getMenuInflater();

        Log.i("HomePageActivity", "HomePage - onCreateOptionsMenu = " + viewPager.getCurrentItem());


        // inflate a different menu depending on which tab we're at
        switch (viewPager.getCurrentItem()){
            case 0:
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
                break;
            case 1:
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
                break;
            case 2:
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu3, menu);
                break;
            default:
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu3, menu);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


    // when option menu is clicked, let fragment handle what action it needs to take
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mAdapter != null) {
           Fragment f = mAdapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
           if(f != null){
                f.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }   
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

=======================================================================
The above codes ALMOST got it to work, except when it invokes child fragment's onOptionsItemSelected. Here's the definition of onOptionsItemSelected() in Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.optionButton:
                try {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SomeNewClass.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

----> Null exception at:
**Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SomeNewClass.class);**

getActivity() doesn't throw an null exception, but **SomeNewClasses.class** does actually. I've tried changing ***getActivity() to getContext() to HomePage.this to getApplicationContext() to pretty much everything I can think of.***

I've spent 3 days on this asynchronous option menu bug and I have not found any solution yet :(  Any tip is greatly appreciated!!!

(this is line works perfectly if menu is inflated in the fragment itself and thus onOptionsItemSelected() is called from within, not from Parent's class like my attempted fix did)

Stack trace:

```
02-01 22:33:09.578  32758-32758/zone.lofo.lofo W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 22:33:09.588  32758-32758/zone.lofo.lofo W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
02-01 22:33:09.588  32758-32758/zone.lofo.lofo W/System.err﹕ at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3826)
02-01 22:33:09.588  32758-32758/zone.lofo.lofo W/System.err﹕ at zone.lofo.lofouser.Fragments.Fragment1.onOptionsItemSelected(Fragment1.java:196)
02-01 22:33:09.588  32758-32758/zone.lofo.lofo W/System.err﹕ at zone.lofo.lofouser.HomePage.onOptionsItemSelected(HomePage.java:112)
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of `getItem()` in your adapter ?

Comment: I don't think this will help, but you don't really need to override the `onOptionsItemSelected` method in the Fragment if you're using the Activity one (just remove the @Overrride annotation)

Comment: @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment0();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment2();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }